# NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "8.0dip" only on Galaxy Tab 2

Tags: android, android-custom-view, numberformatexception, galaxy-tab

I'm currently facing to a glitch from an Galaxy Tab 10.1 2 (GT-P5110) which give me that error, but just on that device. I tried on divers emulators (I use genymotion: Nexus 5-7-10, Galaxy S3-4-5, Galaxy Note 2-3) and devices (Galaxy S -2-3-4, Nexus 5-7).

But just on that Galaxy tab 2 10.1 (GT-P5110) I have this error.

I found this [link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcode.google.com%2Fp%2Fandroid%2Fissues%2Fdetail%3Fid%3D60055&ei=oryyU-W7Ncen4gTBzYCIBA&usg=AFQjCNF5wFVyS2Xo_s5sNb_rn9gqr5HvVg&sig2=0N6WUFORc2TQQEaxFtqDVg&bvm=bv.70138588,d.bGE), but this didn't really help me out to solve that problem.

---

```
07-01 11:06:58.832  14227-14227/com.********.********.com E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class com.package.fr.views.SofiaLiTextView
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at com.package.fr.fragments.TestFragment.onCreateView(TestFragment.java:82)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at com.package.fr.fragments.TestFragment.onCreateView(TestFragment.java:82)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "8.0dip"
            at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
            at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:375)
            at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:366)
            at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.convertValueToInt(XmlUtils.java:123)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getInt(TypedArray.java:254)
            at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:997)
            at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:562)
            at com.package.fr.views.SofiaLiTextView.<init>(SofiaLiTextView.java:55)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at com.package.fr.fragments.TestFragment.onCreateView(TestFragment.java:82)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Because it expects an **integer** value, while `8.0` is a **float**. Solution: pass `8`.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein actually , for me, I use "8dp" as the android:paddingStart value, and I still get this problem...

Comment: @androiddeveloper Did you found a solution to that crash ?

Comment: @zlgdev No. I was hoping this could be a clue of how to handle it. for now, I just use paddingLeft and paddingRight. You could put there dimensions that belong to the appropriate qualifiers. It's a workaround, but should probably work. the qualifier is "ldrtl" for RTL languages and "ldltr" for LTR languages, as shown here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this would be a bug from the Samsung's Android like said [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60055)

Very frustrating  >:)>:)

Comment: How can you solve this problem? was it at least solve by an OS update?

Comment: See the comment above (qualifier ldrt and ldltr) and swap your left/right. Lame. Like samsung.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using android:paddingstart attribute, make sure that your target api level is below 17, else try remove this attribute and run the app. It will work.

Comment: It worked for me when I removed `android:paddingStart` from xml in my Samsung GT-N800 Note 10 running Android 4.1.2

Comment: Removing `android:paddingStart` for all api versions is not the real solution. If you are targeting an api level of lower than 17 make sure you only use `android:paddingStart` on api 17 and above. For anything below api 17 remove `android:paddingStart`

You can do this by moving the styles into values-v17 directory.