# Android - Error inflatinc class - java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: java, android, xml, layout-inflater, numberformatexception

I have strange error in my application but only in Android 4.1 and Samsung Galaxy Note & Tab series:

Galaxy Tab2 10.1 (espresso10wifi), Galaxy Note 10.1 (p4noterf), Galaxy Tab2 10.1 (espresso10rf), Galaxy Note 10.1, (p4notewifi), Galaxy Note 10.1 (p4notewifiww), Galaxy Tab 7.7 (GT-P6800), 
Galaxy Note 10.1 (p4notelte)

Emulators work fine, i have tested with Galaxy S3 & S4, also was ok.

Any help will be appreciated :) Error stack starts like that:

java.lang.NumberFormatException - java.lang.Integer.invalidInt

android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #34: Error inflating class 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)...
...
at aAdapter.getView(aAdapter.java:82)

In my adapter, 82th line just inflates:

row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

My listview item xml file looks like that:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TableRow
            android:id = "@+id/tr1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:shrinkColumns="*"
            android:stretchColumns="*"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:padding="5dip" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id = "@+id/l1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="10"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id = "@+id/lChecked"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/chkChecked"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical|end"
                        android:padding="5dp" />                    

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtANo"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                        android:paddingStart="5dp"
                        android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtPageNo"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:textSize="13sp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/llSeparator"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:background="#dedede" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                        android:layout_gravity="end"
                        android:textAlignment ="gravity"        
                        android:textDirection="rtl" 
                        android:layoutDirection ="rtl"  
                        android:gravity="right" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtABody"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:textAlignment ="gravity"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:layoutDirection ="rtl"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textDirection="rtl"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Stacktrace says: InflateException: Binary XML file line #34. If the layout you posted is the one you are using this is telling you that the problem is in the TextView. Test by leaving a barebone TextView, at least you would have isolated the problem. Then try adding 1 attribute at a time until you find the one causing the error (my wild guess is android:attr/textAppearanceMedium)

Comment: BTW, don't you have a line like this in your stack trace? Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "?2130772074" The number should give you an idea of which is the wrong attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like the Samsung bug reported here:
[NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "8.0dip" only on Galaxy Tab 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24512095/numberformatexception-invalid-int-8-0dip-only-on-galaxy-tab-2)

I had the same issue with using paddingStart / paddingEnd in a layout file. This seems to only happens on Galaxy Tab 2 & Galaxy Note.